# Loop sizes based on category_id

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong with my code? I have `category_id` where 1 is for shoe sizes and 2 for apparel sizes. It shows only val for `category_id(1)` and for `category_id(2)` it shows only "Large". Thanks.

```html
<select class="sm-form-control" name="product_size" id="product_size">
  <option value="">Size</option>
</select>
```

```js
function modal_product_extension(id, category_id) {
    $('#addSize').modal('show');
    $('#addSize').find($('#product_id')).val(id);
    $('#addSize').find($('#categories_id')).val(category_id);
    $('#addSize').find($('#product_price')).val('0');
    $('#addSize').find($('#product_stocks')).val('0');

    var $productSize = $("#product_size")
    if (category_id == "1") {
        var i;
        $productSize.empty()
        for (i = 3; i <= 15; i++) {
            val = i;
            $productSize.append("<option value='"+val+"'>"+ val +"</option>");
        }
    } else if (category_id == "2") {
        $productSize.empty()
        $productSize.append("<option value='S'>Small</option>");
        $productSize.append("<option value='M'>Medium</option>");
        $productSize.append("<option value='L'>Large</option>");
    } else if (category_id == "0") {
        $productSize.empty()
        $productSize.append("<option value=''>Size</option>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use .append() instead of .html()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `html()` *removes* the current content and overwrites it. Hence you will only ever see the last content you set.

To fix the problem use `append()` and `empty()` in the first condition and a single `html()` call in the second condition. Also note that you need to concatenate the `val` variable in the HTML you set in the first condition too. Try this:

```
function modal_product_extension(id, category_id) {
  var $addSize = $('#addSize').modal('show');
  $addSize.find('#product_id').val(id);
  $addSize.find('#category_id').val(category_id);
  $addSize.find('#product_price').val('0');
  $addSize.find('#product_stocks').val('0');

  var $productSize = $("#product_size")
  if (category_id == "1") {
    $productSize.empty()
    for (var i = 3; i <= 15; i++) {
      $productSize.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
    }
  } else if (category_id == "2") {
    $productSize.html('<option value="S">Small</option><option value="M">Medium</option><option value="L">Large</option>');
  } else if (categories_id == "0") {
    $productSize.html('<option value="">Size</option>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to concatenate the var variable. Now the problem is, If I close the modal and open again, the sizes of apparel joins on the sizes of the shoes.

Comment: In that case you need to call `empty()` on all the selects when the modal is opened

Comment: Did calling `empty()` when the modal is loaded as I mentioned before not work?

Comment: Is it possible to upload image and insert data using ajax serialize?

Comment: Yes, but it's a pain and using FormData to send binary file information is a much better approach

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to add multiple options to a select element based on the category id. Right now you are changing the html of the select element instead of adding options to it.

In the snippet below I've replaced your `html` with `append` so it will actually add the options instead of replace it. An example is given with `category_id = 2`.

```js
function modal_product_extension(id, category_id) {

  $('#addSize').find($('#product_id')).val(id);
  $('#addSize').find($('#category_id')).val(category_id);
  $('#addSize').find($('#product_price')).val('0');
  $('#addSize').find($('#product_stocks')).val('0');

  if (category_id == "1") {
    var i;
    for (i = 3; i <= 15; i++) {
      val = i;
      $("#product_size").append("<option value='val'>" + val + "</option>");
    }
  } else if (category_id == "2") {
    $("#product_size").append("<option value='S'>Small</option>");
    $("#product_size").append("<option value='M'>Medium</option>");
    $("#product_size").append("<option value='L'>Large</option>");
  } else if (category_id == "0") {
    $("#product_size").append("<option value=''>Size</option>");
  }
}

modal_product_extension(1, 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="sm-form-control" name="product_size" id="product_size">
</select>
```

Comment: Note that you'll need to clear the old elements out too, otherwise you're infinitely append new options

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Good point. Although it depends on wether the function can be called again or if it is going to be called once.

Comment: Hi. It's working but it loops 'val' on category_id (1).

Category_id(2) works fine. Thanks.

Comment: You are right. The category_id (0) did not properly display the numbers because the 'val' was used as part of the string instead of the value. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to concatenate the var variable. Now the problem is, If I close the modal and open again, the sizes of apparel joins on the sizes of the shoes.